# How to create an instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest for testing?

Tags: c#

I wish to create an instance of HttpRequest with populated data so I can test a method.

I need to pass Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest as a parameter to a function.

How do I instantiate it?

```
[Route("/summary/{id}")]
public IActionResult Account(int id)
{
   var summary = RequestHelper.ParseRequest(Request);
}
```

Options is from the package
https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

```
public static Option<SummaryRequest> ParseRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request== null)
    {
        var query = request.Query;
  
        var result = new SummaryRequest();
    
        var locations = ExtractData(query, "location");
        var categories = ExtractData(query, "categories[]");
        var titles = ExtractData(query, "titles");
    
    }
}
    
public static Option<SummaryRequest> ParseRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request== null)
    {
        var query = request.Query;
            
        var result = new SummaryRequest();
            
        var locations = ExtractData(query, "location");
        var categories = ExtractData(query, "categories[]");
        var titles = ExtractData(query, "titles");
    }
           
    return new SummaryRequest();
}

public static Either<Exception, string[]> ExtractData(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, StringValues>> query, string filter)
{
    try
    {
        return query.First(x => x.Key.ToLower() == filter).Value.ToString().Split(',').ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         return ex;
    }
}
```

### Unit Test Example

```
 [TestMethod]
 [TestCategory(Test.RequestParser)]
 public void ParseRequest_WithHttpRequest_ReturnResultOnSuccess()
 {            
    // var request = this doesn't compile I need an instance of 
    //                 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest
        
     var result = Helper.ParseRequest(request);
 }
```

Comment: Since `HttpRequest` is an abstract type, you can create a mock and setup all expected properties

Comment: Have you considered using [ASP.NET's model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instead of processing the parameters manually, or only passing the query object to the `ParseRequest` method? The query should be somewhat simpler to stub as there is QueryCollection implementation since 3.1 that you can just populate with a dictionary. Alternatively, you can accept the wordy `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, StringValues>>` and use dictionary directly.

Comment: Please take a look on the blog article https://mahmutcanga.com/2019/12/13/unit-testing-httprequest-in-c/

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`Request` property of `DefaultHttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext.request?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_DefaultHttpContext_Request). It's a bit convoluted since you have to specify a lot of properties separately (compared to e.g. [`WebRequest.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-5.0)), but the following worked for me:

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Method = "POST";
httpContext.Request.Scheme = "http";
httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString("localhost");
httpContext.Request.ContentType = "application/json";
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
await writer.WriteAsync("{}");
await writer.FlushAsync();
stream.Position = 0;
httpContext.Request.Body = stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Glorfindel's answer, although good enough for most scenarios fails at a critical one: The default `HttpRequestStream` which is the original stream beneath `Request.Body` is "forward-only" and if you want to read it twice, you need to use `HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering()`.

Now the question, how do you replicate this on a test scenario?: I created a stub implementation:

```
internal sealed class HttpRequestStreamStub : MemoryStream
{
    public HttpRequestStreamStub() { }
    public HttpRequestStreamStub(byte[] buffer) : base(buffer) { }

    public override bool CanSeek => false;

    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Position
    {
        get => throw new NotSupportedException();
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override int WriteTimeout
    {
        get => throw new NotSupportedException();
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override ValueTask WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

it replicates as best as possible the behavior of https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Http/HttpRequestStream.cs